# How do variables get passed in and out of methods in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, polynomials

Currently working on a Class to do arithmetic with polynomials in python as per an assignment. I understand how the arithmetic and the code will work, but I have not used classes before and I dont know how variables get passed in and out of a class... particularly when you want to pass in say... two polynomials and return a function.

I have inserted a function (and want to retool into a method) I have used in the past to multiply a polynomial (with same base, Ill have to amend that per the application needs)

Can someone walk me through the syntax of wanting to input 2 poly's and then multiply them. The videos online aren't very helpful and I could use a step by step ish explanation as to whats happening. This is mostly a syntax issue and the code is in its very early (and broken) stage.

Cheers,
D

EDIT: The form of the polynomial I want to be in this format. intPoly([2,4,1,2], z) is really 2z^3+4z^2+z+2

```
class IntPoly:
    def __init__(build,length,var):
        build.length = length
        build.var = var

    def addPoly:

    def multiply(a, b):
        a.reverse()
        b.reverse()
        c=[0 for x in range(len(a)+len(b)-1)]

        for i in range (len(a)):
            for j in range (len(b)):
                k = a[i]*b[j]
                ii=i+j
                c[ii]+=k

        c.reverse()

        return (c)

    def equalTo:

    def deg:

    def itterate:

    def printReal:
```

Comment: I'd love to help but I'm kind of confused as to what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: If the class is only ever going to handle *two* polynomials, you can just pass them in through the constructor.

Comment: @Devin Your coefficient lists are, imho, reversed.  Isn't it simpler if the power of the polynomial is always equal to the index of the list?  As in "What is the coefficient of the third power term?" your answer would be "Mmhh..." my answer would be "Three, of course"

Comment: Thats why I have that reverse then re-reverse in the function. Allows input to be in the natural math format, but the index then shows the power (i == x^i)

Comment: So, you have to reverse once, reverse twice and eventually reverse every time you operate on polynomials and if this is not enough, take into account that if you want to keep around the original data structures you have either (1) to copy them before reversing or (2) to reverse them again after the computation or (3) to instantiate an iterator by use of `reversed()`. Every time you operate on polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass them in to the constructor. Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
class IntPoly(object):
    def __init__(self, poly1, poly2):
        self.poly1 = poly1
        self.poly2 = poly2

    def multiply():
        """Here you would do your proper conversion and parsing
        given the representation of the polynomials.
        But pretending that they are just numbers, you would do the following:"""
        return self.poly1 * self.poly2
```

And you would create an object like such, and can use the multiply method to get the product:

```
myPolyObject = IntPoly([4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3])
print myPolyObject.multiply()
```

If you needed to account for an arbitrary amount of polynomials, let's call it `n` polynomials, then you could simply keep them all in a list.

```
class IntPoly(object):
    def __init__(self, poly_list):
        self.poly_list = poly_list

    def multiply():
        """Here you would do your proper conversion and parsing
        given the representation of the polynomials.
        But pretending that they are just numbers, you would do the following:"""
        return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, self.poly_list)

myPolyObject = IntPoly([[4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [4, 7, 8]])
print myPolyObject.multiply()
```

The `reduce` function basically takes a function and applies it to each element of the list, collecting the results. So, `reduce(lambda: x,y: x*y, [1, 2, 3])` will result in computing `((1*2)*3))`

Comment: Sorry, the way Im trying to get it to work is in the form say intPoly([2,4,1,2], z) is really 2z^3+4z^2+z+2.

Comment: I would be having less trouble with classes if I could kindof make it all in the constructor.

Comment: Then can you please update your OP because it is really unclear. You don't "pass variables into a class" and classes don't return anything.

Comment: Well that makes more sense to me then, and it seems that a professors wording (Example: IntUPoly([42,0,-3],’y’) represents 42 − 3y^2) is what confuses me. (I assumed by his format he meant to ACTUALLY pass the information into the class) Made the edit for clarity.

Comment: Classes have properties and you can set those properties by passing them to the constructor when you create an object. You can then write methods for that class which will operate on the properties and return values.

Comment: Say you were to do more than 2 polynomials? How would that work. (This is very helpful by the way.)

Comment: @Devin A class is a cake mold, an instance is a cake.  You make a cake (an instance) putting things (eg, the list of coefficients) into the mold (the class).  From one class you can make many different cakes, oops instances.  Here stop the analogy because it's difficult to speak of cakes that, when mated with other cakes, make new cakes according to specific rules (that's methods, by the way).

Comment: @DevinMartin see most recent edit for handling `n` polynomials

Answer (score 0):

```
class Poly():
    """DocString"""
    def __init__(self, loc):
        self.loc = loc
        self.degree = len(loc)
        ...
    ## __add__ is a standard method name, google for python __add__
    def __add__(self, poly2):
        loc1 = self.loc
        loc2 = poly2.loc
        # do stuff and compute loc3, list of coefficients for p1+p2
        return Poly(loc3)
    def __mul__ ...

p1 = Poly([4,3,2,1])
p2 = Poly([3,4,0,0])
p3 = p1+p2
```

If you want to `print` your polynomials, read on the standard methods `__repr__` and `__str__` that python uses for printing or representing custom objects. If you don't care the ability 
of using `print` you can always access the instance's members

```
print "Degree of sum", p3.degree
print "List of coefficients of sum", p3.loc
```